# How to ignore unmatched group in a string in re python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string input of

```
s = 'horse dog cat bear'
```

for which I want to change the order of the words as

```
cat horse dog bear
```

The corresponding `re` would be

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'horse dog cat bear'
>>> print re.sub(r'(horse )(dog )?(cat )(bear)', r'\3\1\2\4', s)
cat horse dog bear
```

I used `(dog )?`, because I still want to match the string when `dog` is not there. Thus output should be `cat horse bear`. But when I tried, I encountered the following error as --

```
>>> s = 'horse cat bear'
>>> print re.sub(r'(horse )(dog )?(cat )(bear)', r'\3\1\2\4', s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 291, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 831, in expand_template
    raise error, "unmatched group"
sre_constants.error: unmatched group
>>>
```

How can I get the output, even if `dog` is not there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
r'(horse )((?:dog )?)(cat )(bear)'
```

I.e. make the contents of the capturing group optional, not the group itself.

Comment: thanks, you saved my day. Can you describe more about what I was missing? I still didn't get it.

Comment: @UjjalKumarDas Apparently python doesn't like it when you try to use the contents of a capture group that wasn't set by the pattern. Your original code made the whole `(...)` group optional (`?`), which either matches it (and sets `\2`) or doesn't match it (and leaves `\2` unset). With my change the `(...)` is not optional; `\2` is always set. It's just that the contents of the capturing group are `(?:dog )?`, which matches either `"dog "` or `""` (the empty string). `(?:...)` is just a way to group a subpattern without capturing anything.

Comment: It now occurs to me that we could get rid of the inner parentheses by doing `(dog |)` instead ("match either `'dog '` or `''` and capture it").

Comment: Curious about `(dog |)`, can you explain it? Also tried `r'(horse )(dog |)(cat )(bear)'` and it worked!

Comment: I mean will `(dog |)` will be set to \2 even if it is `''`? @ melpomene

Comment: @melpomene, your `(dog |)` saved my bacon. Thanks! Ujjal, yes to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `re` ? You can do ti with lists.

```
s0 = 'horse dog cat bear'
s1 = 'horse cat bear'
s_map = 'cat horse dog bear'.split()

print(" ".join([x for x in s_map if x in s0.split()]))
print(" ".join([x for x in s_map if x in s1.split()]))
```

Output:

```
cat horse dog bear
cat horse bear
```