# Python3 re.group several groups even if some are missing

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of duration times formatted like this:

```
['PT1H38M55S', 'PT25M28S', 'PT2H26S', ...]
```

I tried such grouping:

```
import re
re.search('PT([0-9]+|)H?([0-9]+|)M?([0-9]+|)S?', x).group(1, 2, 3)
```

where x is any element from the list, because I want a time() format from it:

```
from datetime import time
def parse_duration(x):
    HMS = re.search('PT([0-9]+)H([0-9]+)M([0-9]+)S', x).group(1, 2, 3)
    return time(int(HMS[0]), int(HMS[1]), int(HMS[2]))
```

But when there is no match, the code breaks.

Is there a solution to fill unmatched search with zero (for example) or another attempt would be easier?

I've found such method, but I couldn't apply it to my case:
[How to ignore unmatched group in a string in re python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989264/how-to-ignore-unmatched-group-in-a-string-in-re-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Match.groups`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups):

```
def parse_duration(x):
    HMS = re.search('PT(?:([0-9]+)H)?(?:([0-9]+)M)?(?:([0-9]+)S)?', x).groups(0)
    return time(*map(int, HMS))
```

Comment: It appears that this solution only captures the H portion of the string and discards the H and M groups due to the non capturing groups. I could be missing something though.

Answer (score 0):

This solution provides tuples that include `None` for missing elements:

```
l = ['PT1H38M55S', 'PT25M28S', 'PT2H26S']
for i in l:
    result = re.search('PT([0-9]+H)?([0-9]+M)?([0-9]+S)?', i)
    if result:
        print(result.groups())
```

Output:

```
('1H', '38M', '55S')
(None, '25M', '28S')
('2H', None, '26S')
```

The regular expression reads as follows:
`([0-9]+H)?` <-- This will match the 1 or more digits followed by a literal `H`, but the entire term is optional because it is followed by a `?`.